# Demonstrating working to a high level with minimal supervision

Tags: applications, meetings

Some job ads ask for something like "Undertake main duties to a high level with minimal supervision". How do I address this in a letter addressing selection criteria?

I can describe that I receive minimal supervision, by indicating that my meetings are not too frequent, or too long, that they are well organised, and that they start at the scheduled meeting time, and that there's minimal time spent by my superiors on supervising outside of meetings.

But how do I describe that I'm undertaking main duties to a high level? That is, that the minimal amount of supervision isn't reducing my productivity?

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, this is a very informal criteria which I have never been requested to specifically prove neither in a cover letter / CV nor in live interview. Probably the stories I told about my past work experience were generally enough to convince interviewers about this.

To me the point of this is whether you are able to solve problems independently, take the initiative when required and be proactive, as opposed to doing only what you were requested to do, then sitting idly until you get the next task, or following orders to the letter without actually understanding the meaning of what you were supposed to do. To show that you belong to the former camp, you may want to include some short and concrete stories from past experience, and/or positive feedback from customers / management on how you went that extra mile or identified / fixed a specific problem proactively.

Answer (score 2):

Most interviewers are able to get a fair idea for themselves of the level of supervision I require for the positions I apply for from my work experience, skills set and how I come across at interviews. If they talk to me at any length, they learn that I know when to ask for supervision e.g. when the task is mission critical and the cost of failure is high, that I am not shy about asking. and that whenever I ask for something - which is not too often, it's because I require it.

As a professional, "undertake main duties to a high level with minimal supervision" is about as redundant to me as telling a US Navy SEAL that he "must be able to get out of tight spots" - What can I say, it's their ads and they can write them any way they wish :)

Answer (score 0):

A high level isn't necessarily an **optimal** level. Give examples of feedback you've received showing high levels of work along with anything indicating your supervisor doesn't have to give additional supervision. Do you require detailed instructions or can you be given the general outcome needed for a task and you work out the details?

There is probably more of a bell-shaped curve on getting supervision and the level of productivity. Too much supervision can just as easily lower your productivity. Your previous experiences may never reach the peak, but it sounds like this company would prefer to err on the side of less supervision.